# I have repaid XMR to OKEX trading platform for 3 months. I haven't arrived. Please help me

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I recharged the XMR from www.OKEX.com trading platform for three months, and it hasn't arrived. Please help me, I'm in a hurry.

Transaction ID:eb150abb70c82a0770c0fa184e31887272b820b5c0843e83189150427c68d513

2018-06-16 19:03:56

Below is a reply from OKEX's customer service staff:

Hello, I'm sorry to have kept you waiting for a long time. It's still an XMR official purse problem. We're actively solving your problem. We'll let you know immediately after the processing is completed that your coin will not be lost. Please rest assured.

Hello, I'm sorry to have kept you waiting for a long time. We're still solving your problem because of the official purse problem of XMR. We're communicating with the government to solve the problem. It's inconvenient for you. Please understand. We'll let you know the result as soon as possible.

Comment: Just tell them to send it back.  They keep saying its a purse (wallet?) issue, then blame the gov't.  Ask them to get their story straight.  Where is this exchange and you located?  if not the same country I doubt you will have any recourse.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see how anyone on StackExchange can help you. You sent XMR to an exchange and that exchange is not crediting your exchange account. Only the exchange can help (if it's not a scam at least). If they are legit, they would either credit your account or refund you the money.